# Laravel 5.1 problemas com csrf_token

Tags: php, session, token, laravel-5.1

Estou com um problema no meu site feito em laravel, acontece o seguinte minha aplicação em laravel não esta retornando o Token de sessão que seria `{{ csrf_token() }}`  quando eu executo uma ação como cadastrar ou logar o mesmo me retorna o seguinte erro:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este erro acontece somente no servidor de produção, tentando resolver acabei identificando que, quando estou acessando o site no servidor de produção o cliente não recebo o token da sessão que deveria ficar em cookies como nas imagens abaixo:

Token da sessão em desenvolvimento:
[image: Token da sessão em desenvolvimento]
Token da sessão em produção:
[image: Token da sessão em produção]
Como deu para vê, é como se a aplicação não retorna-se o token da sessão no servidor de produção, mesmo assim é enviado um token na requisição que e diferente do gerado pela aplicação e gera o erro que informei acima.

Abaixo minhas configurações de sessão no aquivo **.env** `SESSION_DRIVER=file`

Meu session.php

```
<?php

return [
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
    'lifetime' => 120,
    'expire_on_close' => false,
    'encrypt' => false,
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
    'connection' => null,
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => null,
    'secure' => false,
];
```

Se alguém já passou por isso ou sabe algo a respeito que possa ajudar.

Agradeço desde já a sua atenção.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correção desse bugue foi apenas uma modificação no código do meu controller modificando a resposta da requisição `View::make` para `view::make`, por algum motivo a facade de View não adicional os Cookies no cabeçalho requisição http, posso esta enganado no uso das facades, mas isso resolveu meu caso espero ajudar outros.

Answer (score 0):

Entra no arquivo `VerifyCsrfToken.php` dentro de **`App/HTTP/Middleware`** e no array `$except` adicionar a rota no qual não deseja verificar o token.

```
protected $except = [
   'route'/
];
```